# What is the difference between "withdrawal" and "distribution" from a 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, 401k, terminology, withdrawal

My 401(k) plan lists several fees associated with my account.  One of the fees is "Final Distribution", which is "$50.00 per distribution".  Another is "Withdrawal", which is "$50.00 per withdrawal".  I can contact my plan manager for clarification, but before I do, I'm wondering if there is a general distinction between a withdrawal and a distribution used by the financial industry.

Answer (score 8):

This question had better be asked of the 401k plan administrator rather than here. The plan document that you received when you began participating undoubtedly has a page or more of definitions of the terms used in the contract, and especially so if the meanings are nonstandard. For example, one would expect that a Final Distribution leaves a balance of $0 in the 401k account and so a "per distribution" fee is meaningless in the context of Final Distribution.

As the post by mbhunter indicates, *withdrawal* and *distribution* seem to be used interchangeably in
IRS documents, and so there probably is a nonstandard meaning assigned to these
terms in the 401k document.

Three possible nonstandard meanings of these two words come to mind.

- Withdrawal = at the request of the participant,
  and
  Distribution = as required by law, e.g. required minimum distribution
- Withdrawal = anything before age 59.5 or before termination of employment
  and
  Distribution =  anything after age 59.5 or after termination of employment
- Withdrawal = anything on which the 10% excise tax for premature distributions
  must be paid, or anything that is not eligible for rollover into another tax-deferred account
  and
  Distribution = anything on which the 10% excise tax does not need to be paid.

> But all the above is just idle speculation, and what matters is the plan
>   document's definitions of these terms, and that can be determined only
>   if you read your 401k plan document yourself. Reliance on the answers given
>   by the employer's HR department, or the plan administrator, as to what
>   the plan document says might or might not be advisable: even the IRS
>   has been known to give out incorrect information.

**In general**, money cannot be withdrawn from a 401k plan *and*
rolled over (or transferred via a trustee-to-trustee transfer) into
another tax-deferred plan  while the participant
is still employed by the sponsor of the 401k plan. Since most
401k plans have poor investment choices and excessive administrator
fees, reflect that absent this prohibition, most people would with
roll over money from their 401ks into their IRAs as often as feasible.

You *can* withdraw money from a 401k account without paying
the 10% excise tax for several reasons (including financial
needs of various specified kinds), but you cannot then change
your mind and put that money into your IRA, telling the IRA
custodian that it is a rollover from the 401k. To do so
will not just trigger the 10% excise tax on premature
distributions from a 401k account, but you will also need
to pay penalties for excess contributions to your IRA.

Answer (score 6):

The two terms seem to be used interchangeably.  Even the IRS' website [uses them interchangeably](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc424.html) from one sentence to the next (emphasis mine):

> Many 401(k) plans allow employees to make a **hardship withdrawal**
>   because of immediate and heavy financial needs. Generally, **hardship
>   distributions** from a 401(k) plan are limited to the amount of the
>   employees' elective contributions only ...

It might a difference in perspective:  The account holder *withdraws* the money, but the fund manager *distributes* it.

Another way to look at it would be for cases that are only in transition to another tax-advantaged account.  You can *withdraw* the money without it becoming a taxable *distribution* if you get it into another tax-advantaged account within a certain time limit.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you take the money into your hands, there's a mandatory 20% withholding. You were right to equate withdrawal and distribution, with 'transfer' to other account as a distinct option.